# ExtJS Grid doesn't load data

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I'm trying to display data in a grid by using JsonStore.
The grid gets rendered, but it doesn't display the data.

The JSON data returned by API.ashx:

```
[{"Account":{"Username":"root","Password":null,"Enabled":true,"Id":1},"Text":"Hallo Welt!","Id":1},{"Account":{"Username":"root","Password":null,"Enabled":true,"Id":1},"Text":"hihihi","Id":3}]
```

My code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'API.ashx?type=notes&action=getAll',
    root: 'Note',
    autoload: true,
    fields: ['Text', { name: 'Id', type: 'int'}]
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {
            id: 'Note',
            header: 'Id',
            width: 25,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'Id'
        },
        {
            header: 'Text',
            width: 160,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'Text'
        }
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'Note',
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Notes',
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'grid'
});

store.load();

grid.render('grid-example');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed it myself. I had to remove the option "root" and now it works fine.

Comment: when you configure "root" you are pointing to the node of the JSON at which the records should be read. In the sample you've given, it looks like an array of Accounts, so you didn't need to specify one.